# AltBeacon - how to reduce the triggering sensitivity of scanning iBeacon?

Tags: android, altbeacon

I am using AltBeacon and it seems working fairly well.

I am developing an app which triggers an activity when iBeacon is nearby, like 0-2m away from the app.

However, the activity is triggered even when iBeacon is 15-20m away from the app, which is somehow too sensitive for use.

I tried to use the ranging function to calculate the distance between the app and the beacon and to filter out rash triggers. This however causes additional advertising delay. In other words, the scanning period faces long delays up-to 20 seconds even with a very short scanning period setting, e.g., 1 second.

Given this, **can AltBeacon library be configured to reduce the triggering sensitivity to only trigger when iBeacon is very close, like 0-2m?**
(by either having a better use of the ranging function or using any other idea)

Any input will be appreciated!

Regards,

Comment: I don't understand why using ranging causes additional delays.   If you start ranging and monitoring simultaneously, the ranging callback should come within milliseconds of the monitoring callback, and you can use that to check the estimated distance or RSSI.  I think this is the best solution -- but you need to explain why it is causing delays for you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, David. It seems that the ranging function is regarded the only option at this time. I really do not understand why the advertising delays occur.. I will add a comment if I figure out why.